# How to stop parent click firing when clicked on dynamic child form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent grid which bound to a onclick event. Then I have a image which bounds to its own `click` function. I have used  `event.stopPropagation();` to stop the parent div firing when click on this one.

Then on the child click event a form will appear with textboxes , combo boxes etc. That form is wrapped in a `div`. So i used the event propagation to that as well but it does not work. Where ever I clicked on the child form, the parent click event fires.

Is there a solution for this?
html code:

```
<div id="droppable" class="droppable">
</div>
```

script:
    //this is the image click event

```
$('.configClone'+count).on('click', function (event) {
      event.stopPropagation();

      $(this).addClass("selected"+attrId).parent().append('<div id="pop' + attrId + '" class="messagepop pop' + attrId + '"><form method="post" id="new_message" action="/messages"><p><label for="definedStream">Please select the stream</label><select><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option></select></p></form><table border="0"><tr><td><font><b>Attributes</b></font></td><td></td><td><font><b>Assigned Attributes</b></font></td>'+
                        '</tr><tr><td><select id="cmdAllRoles" name="cmdAllRoles" size="6" style="height:100px; width:150px" class="fontDefault" MULTIPLE tabindex="20"></select></td><td valign="middle">'+
                        '<input type="button" id="btnAddRole" name="btnAddRole" value=">" onClick="selectDrag(3)" class="Button-nav" tabindex="15"><br><input type="button" id="btnAddAll" name="btnAddAll" value=">>" onClick="selectDrag(4)" class="Button-nav"><br><input type="button" id="btnRemoveAll" name="btnRemoveAll" value="<<" onClick="selectDrag(1)" class="Button-nav"><br><input type="button" id="btnRemove" name="btnRemove" value="<" onClick="selectDrag(2)" class="Button-nav"><br>'+
                        '</td><td><select id="cmdRoles" name="cmdRoles" size="6" style="height:100px; width:150px" class="fontDefault"></select></td></tr></table></div>');


    //trying to stop propagation from child div
     $(".pop" + attrId).click(function(event) {

          event.stopPropagation();
      alert(5);                   

     });
  }


 $("#droppable").click(function(event) {

    alert(6);
 }
```

alert(6) fires where ever i clicked on the dynamic form.

Problem2: 
I will edit this so its easy to explain. using

```
 $(".pop" + attrId).click(function(event) {

          event.stopPropagation();
      alert(5);                   

     });
  }
```

code, now i can click anywhere on the form without invoking the parent click. The form has a combobox. But i cannot click on the combobox and see the results listing down now. It does not work. I think its because, i wrapped it with the above click event. Any solution for this ?

Comment: Share some code as well

Comment: please create a jsfiddle example

Comment: i will put a code sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `event.stopPropagation();` in child element click also

```
$("#parent").on('click', function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
alert($(this).prop("tagName"));
});
$("#child").on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
alert($(this).prop("tagName"));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UY6Q7/19/)

I checked your edited question. The problem is that, you are dynamically creating tags. These tags should be bind with delegates.

**Example**

```
$(document).on("click",".messagepop",function(event) {

      event.stopPropagation();
  alert(5);                   

 });
```

Comment: Thank i used the event.stopPropagation(); too, there was a problem in my click function. after i fixed it , it worked. But now i have a new problem. In that child form, i have form with a dropdown. since i bound the whole child div to click event, i cannot see the dropdown. do you have solution for this

Comment: @user2281246 I didnt get your question correctly. I would suggest you to ask it as another question

Comment: click of combobox/selectbox to see the content does not work when  we bound the wrapped div to a click event. yes i will do thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to Cancel the default action (navigation) of the child's click event. To do so, You have to use the

```
     event.preventDefault(); 
     event.stopPropagation();
```

in the child element

read more http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/